# Restar días, minutos, segundos entre dos fechas PHP

Tags: php, date

Hice este código, pero algo me dice que esta optimizado muy mal (funcionar funciona de perlas)

¿Hay algo que pueda cambiar para que esté más "optimizado"?

```
        // Contador de FECHA
        $FechaUnlock = array();
        $FechaUnlock[0] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($FechaIngreso[0] . "+ 8 days"));
        $FechaUnlock[1] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($FechaIngreso[1] . "+ 8 days"));
        $FechaUnlock[2] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($FechaIngreso[2] . "+ 8 days"));
        $FechaUnlock[3] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($FechaIngreso[3] . "+ 8 days"));
        $FechaUnlock[4] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($FechaIngreso[4] . "+ 8 days"));

        $df='Y-m-d H:i:s';
        $fechaHoy = new DateTime('d');
        $horahoy = new DateTime('H');
        $minutosHoy = new DateTime('i');
        $segundosHoy = new DateTime('i');

        $fechaFinal = array();
        $fechaFinal[0]  = DateTime::createFromFormat($df, $FechaUnlock[0]);
        $fechaFinal[1]  = DateTime::createFromFormat($df, $FechaUnlock[1]);
        $fechaFinal[2]  = DateTime::createFromFormat($df, $FechaUnlock[2]);
        $fechaFinal[3]  = DateTime::createFromFormat($df, $FechaUnlock[3]);
        $fechaFinal[4]  = DateTime::createFromFormat($df, $FechaUnlock[4]);

        $diffDays = array();
        $diffDays[0] = $fechaFinal[0]->diff($fechaHoy)->d;    #Días que faltan para que termine CASE 0
        $diffDays[1] = $fechaFinal[1]->diff($fechaHoy)->d;    #Días que faltan para que termine CASE 1
        $diffDays[2] = $fechaFinal[2]->diff($fechaHoy)->d;    #Días que faltan para que termine CASE 2
        $diffDays[3] = $fechaFinal[3]->diff($fechaHoy)->d;    #Días que faltan para que termine CASE 3
        $diffDays[4] = $fechaFinal[4]->diff($fechaHoy)->d;    #Días que faltan para que termine CASE 4

        $diffHours = array();
        $diffHours[0] = $fechaFinal[0]->diff($horahoy)->h;    #Horas que faltan para que termine CASE 0
        $diffHours[1] = $fechaFinal[1]->diff($horahoy)->h;    #Horas que faltan para que termine CASE 1
        $diffHours[2] = $fechaFinal[2]->diff($horahoy)->h;    #Horas que faltan para que termine CASE 2
        $diffHours[3] = $fechaFinal[3]->diff($horahoy)->h;    #Horas que faltan para que termine CASE 3
        $diffHours[4] = $fechaFinal[4]->diff($horahoy)->h;    #Horas que faltan para que termine CASE 4

        $diffMins = array();
        $diffMins[0] = $fechaFinal[0]->diff($minutosHoy)->i;     #Minutos que faltan para que termine CASE 0
        $diffMins[1] = $fechaFinal[1]->diff($minutosHoy)->i;     #Minutos que faltan para que termine CASE 1
        $diffMins[2] = $fechaFinal[2]->diff($minutosHoy)->i;     #Minutos que faltan para que termine CASE 2
        $diffMins[3] = $fechaFinal[3]->diff($minutosHoy)->i;     #Minutos que faltan para que termine CASE 3
        $diffMins[4] = $fechaFinal[4]->diff($minutosHoy)->i;     #Minutos que faltan para que termine CASE 4

        $diffSeg = array();
        $diffSeg[0] = $fechaFinal[0]->diff($segundosHoy)->s;     #Segundos que faltan para que termine CASE 0
        $diffSeg[1] = $fechaFinal[1]->diff($segundosHoy)->s;     #Segundos que faltan para que termine CASE 1
        $diffSeg[2] = $fechaFinal[2]->diff($segundosHoy)->s;     #Segundos que faltan para que termine CASE 2
        $diffSeg[3] = $fechaFinal[3]->diff($segundosHoy)->s;     #Segundos que faltan para que termine CASE 3
        $diffSeg[4] = $fechaFinal[4]->diff($segundosHoy)->s;     #Segundos que faltan para que termine CASE 4

        $Tradelock = array();
        $Tradelock[0] = "$diffDays[0]-D&nbsp; $diffHours[0]-H&nbsp; $diffMins[0]-M&nbsp; $diffSeg[0]-S";
        $Tradelock[1] = "$diffDays[1]-D&nbsp; $diffHours[1]-H&nbsp; $diffMins[1]-M&nbsp; $diffSeg[1]-S";
        $Tradelock[2] = "$diffDays[2]-D&nbsp; $diffHours[2]-H&nbsp; $diffMins[2]-M&nbsp; $diffSeg[2]-S";
        $Tradelock[3] = "$diffDays[3]-D&nbsp; $diffHours[3]-H&nbsp; $diffMins[3]-M&nbsp; $diffSeg[3]-S";
        $Tradelock[4] = "$diffDays[4]-D&nbsp; $diffHours[4]-H&nbsp; $diffMins[4]-M&nbsp; $diffSeg[4]-S";
```

$FechaIngreso[ ] sale de una base de datos (básicamente mi súper sistema agarra 2 fechas y le suma 8 días a la primer fecha y luego te descuenta cuanto falta desde esa fecha hasta el momento)

Comment: Así de momento... Podrías hacer un bucle que itere por cada elemento del array fechaIngreso, e ir haciendo las asignaciones dentro del bucle. Por otra parte el $df puedes cogerlo de las constantes de PHP, en lugar de definirlo tu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues sí que se puede optimizar tu código y mucho.

He aquí tu código optimizado, y aún se puede optimizar más, como he puesto en el comentario donde se llena a mano `$fechaFinal`:

---

### Código optimizado sin comentarios

---

```
    $df='Y-m-d H:i:s';        
    $fechaHoy = new DateTime(); 
    $fechaFinal = array();
    /* 
        Esta es la parte más larga que  no me permití modificar
        porque no sé si interesan todos los valores de $FechaIngreso 
        o sólo 4... si son todos esto se puede cambiar por un bucle
    */
    $fechaFinal[]  = DateTime::createFromFormat($df, $FechaIngreso[0])->modify('+8 days');
    $fechaFinal[]  = DateTime::createFromFormat($df, $FechaIngreso[1])->modify('+8 days');
    $fechaFinal[]  = DateTime::createFromFormat($df, $FechaIngreso[2])->modify('+8 days');
    $fechaFinal[]  = DateTime::createFromFormat($df, $FechaIngreso[3])->modify('+8 days');
    $fechaFinal[]  = DateTime::createFromFormat($df, $FechaIngreso[4])->modify('+8 days');

    $mInterval = array();
    foreach ($fechaFinal as $k=>$v){
        $mInterval[]=$v->diff($fechaHoy);
    }
    
    $Tradelock = array();
    foreach ($mInterval as $k=>$v){
        $Tradelock[]="{$v->d}-D&nbsp; {$v->h}-H&nbsp; {$v->i}-M&nbsp; {$v->s}-S";
    }
```

Dado que son muchos cambios, te dejo aquí una versión del mismo código de arriba, pero con los comentarios sobre las cosas que he ido viendo y mejorando.

La moraleja final es que la Programación Orientada a Objetos (POO) aporta unas ventajas enormes que si aprendes a utilizar te ahorrará mucho mucho código como se puede ver sobre todo en los puntos 2, 3, 6, 7 y 8.

---

### Código optimizado con comentarios

---

```
/*
    1. $FechaUnlock es redundante
    -$FechaUnlock = array();
    
    2. Este bloque también es redundante
       Esto lo haremos en el punto (5) más abajo

    -$FechaUnlock[0] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($FechaIngreso[0] . "+ 8 days"));
    -$FechaUnlock[1] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($FechaIngreso[1] . "+ 8 days"));
    -$FechaUnlock[2] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($FechaIngreso[2] . "+ 8 days"));
    -$FechaUnlock[3] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($FechaIngreso[3] . "+ 8 days"));
    -$FechaUnlock[4] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($FechaIngreso[4] . "+ 8 days"));
*/
    $df='Y-m-d H:i:s';
/*
    3. Crear tres objetos distintos es redundante
       Puedes crear un solo objeto sin más 
       y luego usar format sobre ese objeto
       si hicera falta para sacar el día
       las horas, minutos o segundos
       Esta es una de las grandes ventajas de trabajar con objetos
 */
    
    $fechaHoy = new DateTime(); 
    #redundante: $horahoy = new DateTime('H');
    #redundante: $minutosHoy = new DateTime('i');
    #redundante: $segundosHoy = new DateTime('i');

    $fechaFinal = array();
/*
        ATENCIÓN: aquí tu código da un giro copernicano gracias a
                  la flexibilidad que implica trabajar con objetos.
                  Iremos por partes...
    4.  No hace falta indicar el índice para el array $fechaFinal
        pues PHP lo hace por sí solo
    4a. POSIBLE OPTIMIZACIÓN:
        Aquí si se tratase de crear una fecha con cada elemento de $FechaIngreso
        se podría implementar un bucle, pero como no lo sé, dejo la parte de
        $FechaIngreso citando sus índices a mano: 0,1,2,3,4
    5.  OPTIMIZACIÓN COPERNICANA:
        En el punto (1) más arriba dijimos que $FechaUnlock era redundante
        porque aquí tu puedes crear tu array de fechas finales 
        sumando 8 días a la fecha que haya en $FechaIngreso
        aplicando directamente el método modify
        NÓTESE que aquí usaremos $FechaIngreso como cadena para crear la fecha
*/
    $fechaFinal[]  = DateTime::createFromFormat($df, $FechaIngreso[0])->modify('+8 days');
    $fechaFinal[]  = DateTime::createFromFormat($df, $FechaIngreso[1])->modify('+8 days');
    $fechaFinal[]  = DateTime::createFromFormat($df, $FechaIngreso[2])->modify('+8 days');
    $fechaFinal[]  = DateTime::createFromFormat($df, $FechaIngreso[3])->modify('+8 days');
    $fechaFinal[]  = DateTime::createFromFormat($df, $FechaIngreso[4])->modify('+8 days');

/*
    6. Lo que ocurre aquí es una OPTIMIZACIÓN HIPERCOPERNICANA
       De nuevo entendemos aquí la potencialidad de trabajar con objetos
       Así como en el punto (3) dijimos que no hacía falta crear por separado
       objetos para el día, la hora, los minutos, etc...
       TAMPOCO AQUÍ hace falta calcular las diferencias por separado
       y es que `diff` ¡te devuelve un objeto con las diferencias en todo!
       o sea, diferencia en días, en horas, en minutos, etc
       El único cálculo que hay que hacer es este: $diffDays = $fechaFinal->diff($fechaHoy);
       y tendrás en $diffDays todo lo que necesites. Te recomiendo que hagas un var_dump
       de $diffDays para que veas todo lo que tiene dentro... Luego si quieres la diferencia en
       días, haces $diffDays->d  y así... Eso significa que 
       puedes portar únicamente $diffDays sin más a donde lo necesites...
*/
    #Renombraremos la variable, por claridad...
    $mInterval = array();
/*
    7. Aquí sí estoy seguro de la extensión del array
       por lo tanto usaré un bucle.
       Por lo dicho en (6), quitaremos todas las d, 
       para tener el objeto limpio
*/
    foreach ($fechaFinal as $k=>$v){
        $mInterval[]=$v->diff($fechaHoy);
    }
/*
    Todo esto fuera: HIPER OPTIMIZACIÓN...
    
    $mInterval[] = $fechaFinal[0]->diff($fechaHoy)->d;    #Días que faltan para que termine CASE 0
    $mInterval[] = $fechaFinal[1]->diff($fechaHoy)->d;    #Días que faltan para que termine CASE 1
    $mInterval[] = $fechaFinal[2]->diff($fechaHoy)->d;    #Días que faltan para que termine CASE 2
    $mInterval[] = $fechaFinal[3]->diff($fechaHoy)->d;    #Días que faltan para que termine CASE 3
    $mInterval[] = $fechaFinal[4]->diff($fechaHoy)->d;    #Días que faltan para que termine CASE 4

    $diffHours = array();
    $diffHours[0] = $fechaFinal[0]->diff($horahoy)->h;    #Horas que faltan para que termine CASE 0
    $diffHours[1] = $fechaFinal[1]->diff($horahoy)->h;    #Horas que faltan para que termine CASE 1
    $diffHours[2] = $fechaFinal[2]->diff($horahoy)->h;    #Horas que faltan para que termine CASE 2
    $diffHours[3] = $fechaFinal[3]->diff($horahoy)->h;    #Horas que faltan para que termine CASE 3
    $diffHours[4] = $fechaFinal[4]->diff($horahoy)->h;    #Horas que faltan para que termine CASE 4

    $diffMins = array();
    $diffMins[0] = $fechaFinal[0]->diff($minutosHoy)->i;     #Minutos que faltan para que termine CASE 0
    $diffMins[1] = $fechaFinal[1]->diff($minutosHoy)->i;     #Minutos que faltan para que termine CASE 1
    $diffMins[2] = $fechaFinal[2]->diff($minutosHoy)->i;     #Minutos que faltan para que termine CASE 2
    $diffMins[3] = $fechaFinal[3]->diff($minutosHoy)->i;     #Minutos que faltan para que termine CASE 3
    $diffMins[4] = $fechaFinal[4]->diff($minutosHoy)->i;     #Minutos que faltan para que termine CASE 4

    $diffSeg = array();
    $diffSeg[0] = $fechaFinal[0]->diff($segundosHoy)->s;     #Segundos que faltan para que termine CASE 0
    $diffSeg[1] = $fechaFinal[1]->diff($segundosHoy)->s;     #Segundos que faltan para que termine CASE 1
    $diffSeg[2] = $fechaFinal[2]->diff($segundosHoy)->s;     #Segundos que faltan para que termine CASE 2
    $diffSeg[3] = $fechaFinal[3]->diff($segundosHoy)->s;     #Segundos que faltan para que termine CASE 3
    $diffSeg[4] = $fechaFinal[4]->diff($segundosHoy)->s;     #Segundos que faltan para que termine CASE 4
*/

/*
    8. Todavía queda magia por ver, es la magia de la POO
       Vamos a construir todo esto mediante un bucle, 
       y leyendo las propiedades que necesitemos en nuestro objeto
       $mInterval, creado en el punto (7)
 */
    $Tradelock = array();
    foreach ($mInterval as $k=>$v){
        $Tradelock[]="{$v->d}-D&nbsp; {$v->h}-H&nbsp; {$v->i}-M&nbsp; {$v->s}-S";
    }
/*
    Esto sobra... $Tradelock se llenó en el bucle anterior
    
    $Tradelock[0] = "$diffDays[0]-D&nbsp; $diffHours[0]-H&nbsp; $diffMins[0]-M&nbsp; $diffSeg[0]-S";
    $Tradelock[1] = "$diffDays[1]-D&nbsp; $diffHours[1]-H&nbsp; $diffMins[1]-M&nbsp; $diffSeg[1]-S";
    $Tradelock[2] = "$diffDays[2]-D&nbsp; $diffHours[2]-H&nbsp; $diffMins[2]-M&nbsp; $diffSeg[2]-S";
    $Tradelock[3] = "$diffDays[3]-D&nbsp; $diffHours[3]-H&nbsp; $diffMins[3]-M&nbsp; $diffSeg[3]-S";
    $Tradelock[4] = "$diffDays[4]-D&nbsp; $diffHours[4]-H&nbsp; $diffMins[4]-M&nbsp; $diffSeg[4]-S";
*/
```

Comment: muchas gracias por ayudarme con la optimizan y mas que nada por poner los comentarios porque la verdad soy nuevo en php y no entendería si no fuera por ellos

Comment: @Fran me alegro de que te haya servido. Básicamente estabas escribiendo código repetitivo porque no estabas aprovechando todas las ventajas que te da la Programación Orientada a Objetos (POO). Otra cosa que ayudó a optimizar fue el uso de bucles  `foreach`...